# Reference request for literature on the following function--power counting zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

I'll start by writing the character of interest, and describing some properties of it, before I get to the meat of the question. Any help is greatly appreciated, even an offhand suggestion/comment/reference to literature that may only be partially relevant.

Let's start by defining a quasi character $\chi_m(n)$ such that:

$$
\chi_m(n) = 1\,\,\text{if}\,\,n^k = m\,\,\text{otherwise}\,\,\chi_m(n) = 0\\
$$

The first rule that's obvious, is that $\chi_{p^k}(p^t) = 1$ if and only if $t \mid k$--when $p$ is a prime. We will always denote $p$ for a prime, and any list of primes will be a list denoted as $p_1, p_2,....$. Whereupon, the sum of these "quasi characters", can be neatly factored:

$$
Q(p^k)= \sum_{1\le n \le p^k} \chi_{p^k}(n) = \sigma(k)\\
$$

Where $\sigma$ is the divisor function:

$$
\sigma(k) = \sum_{d \mid k} 1\\
$$

When we take:

$$
Q(p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}) = \sum_{a_1 \le k_1} \sum_{a_2 \le k_2} \chi_{p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}}(p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2})\\
$$

We are given the multiplication formula:

$$
Q(p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}) \le Q(p_1^{k_1}) Q(p_2^{k_2}) = \sigma(k_1) \sigma(k_2)\\
$$

This is because the sum:

$$
\sum_{a_1 \le k_1} \sum_{a_2 \le k_2}  \chi_{p_1^{k_1}}(p_1^{a_1} ) \chi_{p_2^{k_2}}(p_2^{a_2})
$$

Over estimates our original function. It is always positive when it is positive, but sometimes it is positive when it is null. I.e: it adds in a bunch of false positives. Through a bit more work, you can show that:

$$
Q(ab) \le Q(a)Q(b)\\
$$

When $(a,b) = 1$ are co-prime. From here, we can introduce the $\Pi$ function, which I write as:

$$
\begin{align}
m &= \prod_i p_i^{k_i}\\
\Pi(m) &= \prod_i \sigma(k_i)\\
\end{align}
$$

Upon which:

$$
Q(m) \le \Pi(m)\\
$$

I'm pretty sure this is a pretty modest bound, nothing to write home about, but it's served me well for a while. Especially considering that $\sigma(n) = O(n^{\epsilon})$.

---

*[Enter the $\nu$ function.]*

The $\nu$ function is a type of zeta function, not sure what type it is. But I know I've seen similar types before, so any help at finding similar functions is greatly appreciated. Take:

$$
\nu(s) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^m Q(m) m^{-s}\\
$$

Here's where I start to get a little iffy. I'm pretty confident that $Q(m) = O(m^{\epsilon} \log(m))$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, but I'm outta shape with my zeta function work, so this could be way off. But ignoring this, momentarily, I'm certain that $\nu(s)$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s) > 1$--which comes from taking a submultiplicative arithmetic functions and bounding growth (the bounded Euler product formula converges for $\Re(s) > 1$; which in turn bounds the coefficients). The function $\Pi(m)$ is multiplicative, and its zeta function converges for $\Re(s) > 1$.

My question, and what I'm looking for referential literature to study upon, comes from this. I believe $\nu(s)$ is analytically continuable to $\Re(s) > 0$ (meromorphic here, there are probably poles). And the manner I want to do this, is to just follow the standard "Abel summation" then "rearrange the integral" manner that Dirichlet always uses.

So if I write:

$$
A(x) = \sum_{1 \le n \le \lfloor x \rfloor} (-1)^nQ(n)\\
$$

We can re-express $\nu$ as:

$$
\nu(s) = -s \int_1^\infty A(x)x^{-s-1}\,dx\\
$$

My hypothesis is that we can get a tight bound of $A(x) = O(x\log(x))$, or something like $A(x) = O(x^{1+\epsilon}\log(x))$. (If we can do even better, I would love that too, wouldn't be surprised if the $(-1)^n$ provides more cancellation than I'm counting for.) From which, we'd be able to grow the domain of holomorphy using the standard Dirichlet technique. (The following is a naive story board of what I mean to do, this is not the answer, but the integrals and stuff react something like this!):

$$
\nu(s) = s\int_1^\infty\left(C x\log(x) - A(x)\right)x^{-s-1}\,dx - \frac{Cs}{(s-1)^2}\\
$$

For some magical $C$. I don't expect it to actually work out that simply, but I believe as a story board, it'll look something like this. If we get a different elementary function $E(x) = O(x^a \log(n))$ where $E(x)$ is something integrable in a nice manner, I'll be satisfied with that too. Upon which the error: $A(x) = E(x) + O(x^{\delta})$ is something of this form. Where we can at least get $\Re(s) > \delta$ for our analytic continuation.

---

I'm mostly just looking for literature on $\chi_m(n)$, or $Q(m)$, or on the function $\nu(s)$. These aren't the functions I'm actually interested in, but these are intimately related to the zeta function I am investigating. And I'd love to see how other mathematicians have handled these things. Considering the relatively simple nature of these functions, I don't doubt for a second that other mathematicians have touched upon these things.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!